# mockk every {}.throws() Exception fails test

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I need to verify that a certain call is not made, when a previous method call throws an Exception.

```
    // GIVEN
    every { relaxedMock.eats() }.throws(NotHungryException())
    
    // WHEN
    sut.live()
    
    // THEN
    verify (exactly = 0) { relaxedMock2.sleeps() }
```

Problem with this code, it fails because of the Exception thrown and not because of the failed verification.

Comment: So `sut.live()` throws an exception, which fails your test?

Comment: I think you can only expect that certain exception is thrown. It's no point to test language basic behaviour: if something thrown - method flow will be interrupted.

Comment: whatever @standalone said makes sense. but in case you still want to try out, then surround call to `live()` with try/catch, and then the verify call outside the try block

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I understand that your *WHEN* block will always throw an exception.
In that case you have multiple options from my point of view:

1. Simple plain Kotlin. Wrap the *WHEN* block with a try-catch block, e.g. like this:

```
// GIVEN
every { relaxedMock.eats() }.throws(NotHungryException())
    
// WHEN
var exceptionThrown: Boolean = false
try {
    sut.live()
} catch(exception: NotHungryException) {
    // Maybe put some assertions on the exception here.
    exceptionThrown = true
}
assertTrue(exceptionThrown)
    
// THEN
verify (exactly = 0) { relaxedMock2.sleeps() }
```

2. For a bit nicer code, you can use [JUnit5 API's Assertions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html). `assertThrows` will expect an exception being thrown by a specific piece of code. It will fail the test, if no exception is thrown. Also it will return the thrown exception, for you to inspect it.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions

// GIVEN
every { relaxedMock.eats() }.throws(NotHungryException())
    
// WHEN
val exception = Assertions.assertThrows(NotHungryException::class.java) { sut.live() }
    
// THEN
verify (exactly = 0) { relaxedMock2.sleeps() }
```

3. If you're using [Kotest](https://kotest.io/docs/assertions/core-matchers.html) you can use the `shouldThrow` assertion. Which also allows you to retrieve the thrown exception and validate its type.

```
import io.kotest.assertions.throwables.shouldThrow

// GIVEN
every { relaxedMock.eats() }.throws(NotHungryException())
    
// WHEN
val exception = shouldThrow<NotHungryException> { sut.live() }
    
// THEN
verify (exactly = 0) { relaxedMock2.sleeps() }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue and found that my method is not surrounded by try catch. This mean the method will always throw exception.

***Test***

The unit test to verify the result when the following method is called while stubbing it with predefine Exception

```
    @Test
fun returnSearchError() {

    every { searchService.search(query) }.throws(BadSearchException())

    val result = searchRepository.search(query)

    assertEquals(SearchStates.SearchError, result)

}
```

**Faulty code**

```
    fun search(query: String): SearchStates {
    val result = searchService.search(query)   // No try catch for the thrown exception 
    return try {
        SearchStates.MatchingResult(result)
    } catch (badSearchException: BadSearchException) {
        SearchStates.SearchError
    }
}
```

**Refactored it to**

```
fun search(query: String): SearchStates {
    return try {
        val result = searchService.search(query)
        SearchStates.MatchingResult(result)
    } catch (badSearchException: BadSearchException) {
        SearchStates.SearchError
    }
}
```