# Mock throwing of Exception with Android Coroutines

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

I am introducing coroutines to an android app I am working.  There is lots of legacy but I am now adding some new networking code and using coroutines for it.

**EDIT**
Updating to add the whole test

```
coEvery { service.getAddress(any(), any(), any()) } coAnswers { throw Exception("Test Exception") }
val subject = repository.getAddress(123, "en", null)

coVerify(exactly = 1) { service.getAddress(any(), any(), any())}
```

So the line `coEvery { service.getAddress(any(), any(), any()) } coAnswers { throw Exception("Test Exception") }` in the test on it's own doesn't cause an issue.  It falls down when adding `val subject = repository.getAddress(123, "en", null)`

**EDIT 2 TO INCLUDE REPO**
Here is the repo:

```
class AddressRepository (
    val addressRestService: AddressRestService,
    val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
){
    suspend fun getAddress(
        wlid: Int,
        locale: String?,
        googleAddressObject: GeoResponse?
    ) : AddressForm = withContext(dispatcher) {
             addressRestService.getAddress(wlid, locale, googleAddressObject)
    }
}
```

I am using clean architecture and I am trying to test my repository.  I am using the Mockk lib and I am trying to test a failure.

Below is a snippet:

```
coEvery {
    service.getAddress(123, "en", null)
} throw Exception()
```

When running the above I get test failure with the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.Exception
    at **.*******.data.repository.AddressRepositoryTest$when getAddress is called, returns false$1.invokeSuspend(AddressRepositoryTest.kt:52)
    at **.*******.data.repository.AddressRepositoryTest$when getAddress is called, returns false$1.invoke(AddressRepositoryTest.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt$runBlockingTest$deferred$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:50)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineDispatcher.dispatch(TestCoroutineDispatcher.kt:50)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:322)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.async(Builders.common.kt:91)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.async(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.async$default(Builders.common.kt:82)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.async$default(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:49)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:73)
    at at **.*******.data.repository.AddressRepositoryTest$when getAddress is called, returns false(AddressRepositoryTest.kt:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:119)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I have tried different variations e.g.

```
coEvery {
    service.getAddress(123, "en", null)
}.coAnswers {
    throw Exception()
}
```

When running the above I get a test failure with the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.Exception
    at **.****.******.data.repository.AddressRepositoryTest$when getAddress is called, returns false$1$2.invokeSuspend(AddressRepositoryTest.kt:53)
    at **.****.******.data.repository.AddressRepositoryTest$when getAddress is called, returns false$1$2.invoke(AddressRepositoryTest.kt)
    at io.mockk.MockKStubScope$coAnswers$1.invokeSuspend(API.kt:2112)
    at io.mockk.MockKStubScope$coAnswers$1.invoke(API.kt)
    at io.mockk.CoFunctionAnswer$answer$1.invokeSuspend(Answers.kt:33)
    at io.mockk.CoFunctionAnswer$answer$1.invoke(Answers.kt)
    at io.mockk.JvmCoroutineCall.callCoroutine(InternalPlatformDsl.kt:212)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.mockk.JvmCoroutineCall.callWithContinuation(InternalPlatformDsl.kt:217)
    at io.mockk.CoFunctionAnswer.answer(Answers.kt:34)
    at io.mockk.impl.stub.AnswerAnsweringOpportunity.answer(AnswerAnsweringOpportunity.kt:14)
    at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.answer(MockKStub.kt:54)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.AnsweringState.call(AnsweringState.kt:16)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.call(CommonCallRecorder.kt:53)
    at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.handleInvocation(MockKStub.kt:263)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper$mockHandler$1.invocation(JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:25)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.Interceptor.call(Interceptor.kt:20)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.BaseAdvice.handle(BaseAdvice.kt:42)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.jvm.JvmMockKProxyInterceptor.interceptNoSuper(JvmMockKProxyInterceptor.java:45)
    at **.****.******.data.api.AddressRestService$Subclass0.getAddress(Unknown Source)
    at **.****.******.data.repository.AddressRepository$getAddress$2.invokeSuspend(AddressRepository.kt:18)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineDispatcher.dispatch(TestCoroutineDispatcher.kt:50)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.internal.TestMainDispatcher.dispatch(MainTestDispatcher.kt:35)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:322)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:170)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source)
    at **.****.******.data.repository.AddressRepository.getAddress(AddressRepository.kt:17)
    at **.****.******.data.repository.AddressRepositoryTest$when getAddress is called, returns false$1.invokeSuspend(AddressRepositoryTest.kt:56)
    at **.****.******.data.repository.AddressRepositoryTest$when getAddress is called, returns false$1.invoke(AddressRepositoryTest.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt$runBlockingTest$deferred$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:50)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineDispatcher.dispatch(TestCoroutineDispatcher.kt:50)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:322)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.async(Builders.common.kt:91)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.async(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.async$default(Builders.common.kt:82)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.async$default(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:49)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:73)
    at **.****.******.data.repository.AddressRepositoryTest.when getAddress is called, returns false(AddressRepositoryTest.kt:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:119)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I would very much appreciate if anyone could point out where I'm going wrong.. if it is possible to mock throwing an exception with coroutines.  Any tips appreciated

Comment: what's the return type from getAddress? Apart from that, you are causing the test to crash because you are throwing an exception while executing the test.

Comment: @gyosida the return type is an address dto. I will have a scenario whereby my backend might return a 501 exception.  So I need to test that path.  Is there a way to do this with Mockk and suspend functions?

Comment: Probably related to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66973130/3648678 check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [`JUnit Jupiter`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/) library, it allows to test throwing Exceptions by using [`assertThrows`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows-java.lang.Class-org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable-) method. For example if you want to test that `service.getAddress()` function throws some `Exception` under certain conditions you can test it like the following:

```
assertThrows<Exception> { service.getAddress(123, "en", null) }
```

This assertion checks whether `getAddress` throws `Exception` exception. You can replace `Exception` with another type you want to test.

---

If you want to throw an Exception you can use `throws` infix function:

```
coEvery { service.getAddress(123, "en", null) } throws NullPointerException("Error occurred")
```

---

I guess the error you get is happening due to incorrect return value. Please try to return `AddressForm` object instead of throwing an `Exception`:

```
coEvery { service.getAddress(any(), any(), any()) } returns AddressForm(...)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.  So if I want to mock that the `getAddress()` method would throw an Exception, can I do this with Junit Jupiter?

Comment: with my answer you can test whether `getAddress()` function throws an exception under certain conditions. Please see my updated answer regarding throwing an Exception.

Comment: thanks Sergy, yes I had updated my OP above with that, however I still get the above error when calling the suspend function `val subject = repository.getAddress(123, "en", null)` afterwards so I'm not sure what's happening there

Comment: please see my updated answer regarding the error you get.

Comment: I have done that, I have tested the happy path.  Now I want to test the unhappy path by mocking an exception being thrown

Comment: If you are certain that under some conditions the function throws an exception, then use `assertThrows<Exception> { service.getAddress(...) }` to test it. Replace `Exception` with needed type.

Comment: @Sergio But the assertThrows<Exception> { service.getAddress(...) } won't work with the `getAddress(...)` as it it a suspended function. @DJ-DOO how did it work with you for marking the answer as accepted?